# Laravel passing a variable to a method from a view

Tags: php, laravel

I have a view called settings.blade.php

I want to have a button which when clicked calls a function in my HomeController.

settings.blade.php:

```
<a href="{{action('HomeController@download', Auth::user()->id)}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Download my user data</button></a>
```

The idea is it grabs the user_id and sends it in the function to HomeController@download

When I run this, I get this error

```
Action App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@download not defined. (View: C:\inetpub\www\laravel\baconator\resources\views\settings.blade.php)
```

However it's defined

```
public function download($id){
    return $id;
}
```

At the moment it just returns the ID as I'm testing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have the route properly defined. Please post your routing config.

Comment: Yea I don't have a route defined! That will be the issue. Silly me!
Is there anyway, I can create a route which cannot be accessed via a URL? I don't really want people to be able to browse to access this function, I guess I can put some security to stop the function running, but is there a better way?

Comment: Adding a route fixed it! But how do I pass a parameter to the method? The way I tried above doesn't work! :(

Answer (score 1):

Define you route like this

```
Route::get('user/{user}', 'UserController@download')->name('downloadUser');
```

and define `href` like this

```
{{ route('downloadUser',[Auth::user()->id]) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

For eg:-
In your route file add a route

```
Route::get('/example/{user_id?}', 'HomeController@download')->name('download');
```

In your view file change html to

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='{{url('/example').'/'.Auth::user()->id}}'" type="button" ></button>
```